# Why can't the genesis block be found I create an altcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core, altcoin, genesis-block

I have built the bitcoin source code with a new `pszTimestamp`, `hashGenesisBlock` and `hashMerkleRoot`

The code builds fine and does not run into any `assert` problems when validating these hashes on `[line 128 and line 129 of chainparams.cpp]`. (Great)

### However...

When I run `bitcoin-qt` I run into the error below:

`Error: Incorrect or no genesis block found. Wrong datadir for network?`

### Potential Cause:

Is the reason I am encountering this error because I have not yet mined the genesis block? If so how do I do that? It seems that in the bitcoin code there is nothing about mining the genesis block. I have heard rumours that this functionality was removed and that I will have to download a separate program for this step. Please confirm.

Comment: I met same problem. I met CBlockDiskPos(nFile=0, nPos=8) error or AcceptBlock: high-hash, proof of work failed (code 16) error.  Have you solved? Any updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thant is correct. You have to mine the genesis block first separately if you are compiling the most recent bitcoin codebase.

Checkout : https://github.com/vlamer/genesis-block-generator

Comment: Is it still work with newest litecoin source? (0.15.1)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of that but since its a complete copy of bitcoin source, I don't think anything would be different.